# Laravel prevent open route in browser

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, axios

I'm very new to `laravel` and created my first `REST api` project with it, then I set `cors` middleware and it works perfectly, one thing is so important to me, that prevent open route with `GET` method in browser directly, I don't know how to allow `api` return data only when it called form my own website not directly in browser. I googled and found this **[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32584975/4540183)**

```
public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
    {
        if ( ! $request->ajax())
            return response('Forbidden.', 403);

        return $next($request);
    }
```

So it works fine and if you open route in browser directly like `site.com/api/car/index` it return `403` error, but it return this error in my website too! my website created with `reactjs/nextjs` and use `axios` to call `api`, any idea how to fix this? or is there better solution to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case will recommend to look towards the next solution:

```php
function handle(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, \Closure $next)
{
    $allowedList = env('allowed_user_agents');
    if (! in_array($request->userAgent(), $allowedList, true)) {
        return response('Forbidden.', 403);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

This is base idea, but should work for your problem :)

UPD:

More fluent solution:

```php
function handle(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, \Closure $next)
{
    $allowedList = env('allowed_user_agents', ['PostmanRuntime/7.29.0']);
    if (! in_array($request->userAgent(), $allowedList, true)) {
        return abort(\Illuminate\Http\Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

UPD2:
Taking into account the feedback from comments.
Add env variable which will represent user agent name of your FE application.

```
ALLOWED_USER_AGENT='Fe SPA client'
```

Add it config, in my case i am using config/cors.php:

```php
'allowed_user_agent' => env('ALLOWED_USER_AGENT', 'default-name')
```

Middleware:

```php
function handle(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, \Closure $next)
{
    $spaUserAgent = config('cors.allowed_user_agent');
    
    if ($request->userAgent() !== $spaUserAgent) {
        return abort(\Illuminate\Http\Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Axios config:

```js
axios
    .get(requestUrl, {
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Fe SPA client'
        }
    })
```

Comment: `env()` returns a value from the `.env` file. and you have not included the `allowed_user_agents`'s value in your answer. please consider adding it or your answer is useless.

Comment: Please explain more about your solutions, not figured out yet

Comment: @AdisonMasih Thanks for feedback 
@tourtravel i`ve updated my idea, please let me know if it works for you

Comment: Nice solution, it working good